# Celery AsyncResult - Not working

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am new to celery but failing at what should be simple:

Backend and broker are both configured for RabbitMQ

Task as follows:

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Test Code:

File 1:

```
from tasks import add
from celery import uuid
task_id = uuid()
result = add.delay(7, 2)
task_id = result.task_id
print task_id
# output = 
         05f3f783-a538-45ed-89e3-c836a2623e8a
print result.get()
# output = 
          9
```

File 2:

```
from tasks import add
from celery.result import AsyncResult

res = AsyncResult('05f3f783-a538-45ed-89e3-c836a2623e8a')
print res.state
# output =
         pending
print ('Result =  %s' %res.get())
```

My understanding is file 2 should retrieve the value success and 9.

I have installed flower:

This reports success and 9 for the result.

Help. This is driving me nuts.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should [read the FineManual](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#rpc-result-backend-rabbitmq-qpid) and think twice ?

> **RPC Result Backend (RabbitMQ/QPid)**
>
> The RPC result backend (rpc://) is special as **it doesn’t actually store the states**, but rather sends
>   them as messages. This is an important difference as it means that a
>   **result can only be retrieved once**, and **only by the client that
>   initiated the task**. Two different processes can’t wait for the same
>   result.
>
> (...)
>
> **The messages are transient (non-persistent) by default, so the results
>   will disappear if the broker restarts**. You can configure the result
>   backend to send persistent messages using the result_persistent
>   setting.

Comment: Your correct. rpc:// has this opeation. I am not using rpc://. I am using ampq. So the results should be on the message Q? There is no mention of what happens when using ampq as the backed.

Comment: rpc is the only RabbitMQ backend in celery 4.x, cf http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-result-backend-settings. If you're using an older version (3.x), please refer to the relevant doc: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#amqp-backend-settings - which FWIW doesn't seem to persist results either.

Comment: To make a long story short: use a persistent result backend if you want to persist results. Also and FWIW, the "PENDING" state really means "UNKNOWN" state (from the author's own words), so getting a PENDING state for a task you _know_ has been executed means the results are nowhere to be found in the results backend.

Comment: Thank you So the only way to get results is a DB backend. Will Redis work?

Comment: That's not "the only way to get results" but that's the only way to make sure your results will survive a backend restart and will be accessible from another process. And yes redis works fine and is probably the best "default" backend choice for most situations (easy to set up, low overhead, can persist your results and even take care of cleaning up older results by itself).

Comment: Would you use Redis for the Q as well or stay with Rabbit?

Comment: Depends on your needs and constraints, but celery has really been designed with RabbitMQ broker / Redis backend as the main target, and RabbitMQ has a lot of very useful features when you start having to worry about performances, robustness and scaling. Remember that RabbitMQ has been designed to be an async distributed message queue, redis to be an efficient in-memory (with persistence options) key:value database.